# Why is there a minimum word count requirement to answers? And yet another instance of unfair moderation

Tags: discussion, moderators

So, the moderator deleted an answer of mine

(related Q [Holy cows and plastic bags](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/47/holy-cows-and-plastic-bags/5422?noredirect=1#comment27222_5422))

The reasons given are unsatisfactory; I quote a portion of it " they shouldn't just be three lines long."

Why not? Just because it is one individual's style to write essays does not make the style superior or desirable.

Secondly, the other answers do not have scriptural references either but were not deleted.

This unfair , uneven moderation has been called out time and again ;yet the moderator in question persists. What gives?

Comment: Those other two answers were written in the site's early days, before firm rules were established, so they're grandfathered in.  In any case I wouldn't just delete a short answer if it provided details and sources.  Answers on this site should be backed up with sources (preferably scripture), so that people can easily verify that they're correct.

Comment: I also agree with many points in this [question](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/361/voting-to-have-keshav-srinivasan-take-a-sabbatical-as-a-moderator) of yours. But moonstar2001 you should also improve the quality of your answers.

Comment: Is your deleted answer still visible to you? If yes, you should probably post your answer 'as is' here if you want others input on it ;-)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan This reason/excuse has gotten old. My answer too is at least a year old.  Some archeological program going on here?

Comment: @sv. In principle, I don't have a problem with my answers getting deleted. Certainly have a problem with them getting deleted :- 1. for the wrong , reasons. An answer getting deleted because it is "3 lines long" is laughable 2. Years after they have been posted like the deletion is part of some special target program 3. Unfairly (as in only my answers get deleted and insubstantial excuses are provided as reasons for the selective targeting).

Comment: @moonstar2001 No, I don't generally go digging for answers - your answer was just flagged today.  A site like this is too big to look through ourselves, so for the most part we rely on people flagging content for us, although of course if we spot something ourselves we take action then too.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Why did the flag on my question not prompt you to take similar action on other answers that are "guilty" of the same lapse?

Comment: @moonstar2001 Because the other two answers were written in the first month of the site's existence, back before firm rules were established, so they're "grandfathered in".  Those same answers would not be acceptable if they were posted today.

Comment: @Sandeep Feel free to downvote the answers. Or edit. Those edits may or may not be retained based on their merit.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan That is not an acceptable answer. Rules are still fluid.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Well, you may not like the rules that are currently in effect, but at least for the time being they are in effect, and when the site first started there were no clear rules.  It's only some time after the site went into public beta that it was decided that answers have to be backed up with reliable sources.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think mods can add a 'citation needed' banner or [notice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165006/187039) on old answers that don't meet the current site rules. Also consider using a '[historical lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)' on bad questions such as [this one](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/346/2995).

Comment: @sv. Yeah, adding post notices to grandfathered answers seems like a good idea.  And yeah, I wasn't aware of historical locks, but they seem ideal for questions like the one you linked to.  I just locked it.

Comment: @moonstar2001 If you think, there are other answer, which should be deleted then why not flag it? You have power of flag and comment for that purpose. Sometime we do give sometime for improvement for new user, but that doesn't means comment like answer are allowed.

Comment: Tell me honestly, don't you think it's a comment?

Comment: To support ur answer by quoting from scriptures is good and must follow rule.But having minimum word limits is not necessary.Let the user try if he/she can fit in the sources and his own texts within a very "short" word limit.In all probability he/she can't.:) So the rule on word limits is redundant.

Comment: @Rickross There isn't really a rule on word count.  If post answers the question and provides adequate details and sources, I wouldn't just delete it because it's short.

Comment: @sv. I decided to unlock the question and close it instead.  I thought locking just meant closing the question and putting a post notice saying that it's kept for historical reasons, but it prevents editing of questions and answers and there's point in doing that.  I wish there was a way to put the historical post notice without doing an actual lock, but it seems like I'm not able to create custom post notices.

Comment: @Mr.Alien My ability to articulate my thoughts must be really poor. I am not complaining against the deletion. I am complaining against the reasons for deletion. And against not deleting other answers to which the same "reasons" apply. I am complaining against bad rules and against bias

Answer (score 8):

The deleted answer in question is (I am not the flagger BTW):

[image]

To me, it indeed looks more like a comment. Comparing with the other answers, they have given some references, but your answer doesn't provide that. Moreover, you have [agreed in past](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/454/1049), that scriptural references are necessary for this site.

---

But if still there is a complain, then better way is described here:
[What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/163449)

Comment: 1. I have no problem with answers being deleted, per se. My  objections are different   2. How are you able to view deleted answers?

Comment: @moonstar2001 High reputation users have a lot of abilities that mods do, including viewing deleted posts; see here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges